# Using IndexedDB with Kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, indexeddb, dexie

I'm working on an application that is supposed to work online. I'm using IndexedDB as the local storage. But my problem is that I'm dealing with a Kendo grid and it's been called from a database on a server with an API. I want to know how to get the Kendo grid data so that I can save it locally in IndexedDB. This is what I'm using now. I'm actually using the dexie.js library.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //saving data to local database
    var formObj = {};

    var db = new Dexie('IML-Inspection');
    db.version(1).stores({
        //schema for database
        inspections: '++id'
    });

    db.open().then(function () {

        db.inspections.toArray().then(function (fData) {
            if (fData.length === 0) {
                db.inspections.put(formObj);
                console.log('Inserted blank record');
            };
        });
    });
    //$('td').each(function () {
    $('#grid').bind('td').on('click', function () {
        console.log("input blurred");

        db.transaction("rw", db.inspections, function () {
            db.inspections.toArray().then(function (fData) {

                fData = fData[fData.length - 1];//holds the most recent data in array

                //convert form data to object
                formObj = $('form').serializeObject();
                db.inspections.update(fData.id, formObj);
            });
        });
    });





});//end of document.ready function
```